# Are there any criteria in determing whtether to implement a function by inline or by macro in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

As in linux kernel source, I found many functions with tiny body implemented in inline form, and many other functions also with a tiny body implemented in MACRO.

So I wonder what is the consideration involved when determine to choose which one, cause I think both are apropriate. Or this is just sort of personal style?

Answer (score 1):

Macros don't do type-checking and require other special considerations (i.e. evaluating an expression exactly once), so they should be avoided wherever possible. Not checking the type however has the advantage of allowing you to write generic functions in C89.

Also writing real `inline` functions allows (using a certain flag that can be activated in the kernel's config) the compiler to also uninline it if this has performance advantages, while this is not possible with a macro, being a simple text substitution.

Answer (score 0):

macros being textual substitutions can do more than inlined functions. They may also have unwanted side effects. consider the well known swapping macro.

```
#define SWAP(a,b) {int t=a; a=b; b=t}
```

and notive that `SWAP(i,t[i])` do unwanted things.

Inlined functions have the advantage of having function-call like semantics (arguments are evaluated once, etc...).

So it is mostly a matter of coding style, and of recognizing that macros & functions are different kind of animals.

And you question is not really relevant specifically to the kernel. Any C (or even C++) program have the same issue.

Comment: Since kernel uses lots of extensions of GCC, like _____attribute_____ ,etc. So I think the side-effect factor must not be within consideration, cause **statement expression** can handle this. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs

Comment: No, the GCC extensions don't really always help (even if they are very convenient), as my simple `SWAP` example shows.

Comment: As for the side-effect thing, I think gcc extension is competent. But I agree with you that it's mostly a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a lot of code in the Linux kernel has been there for quite some time. Some of the macros also do "clever stuff" with other parts of the input/environment than a function would/could/should do.

As a general rule, use (inline) functions whenever possible, as there are fewer "gotcha's" with functions, as explained above.

If you do clever replacement or some other "can only do in macro", it's generall better to make a macro that forms the arguments to a function if possible. E.g.

```
#define ASSERT(x)  do { if (!(x)) { fprintf(stderr, "Assertion failed on %s:%d", __FILE__, __LINE__); exit(1); } while(0);
```

could be done as:

```
#define ASSERT(x) do_assert(!!(x), __FILE__, __LINE__);

void do_assert(bool val, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (!val)
    {
        fprintf(....);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Now you can, for example, in a debug build, set a breakpoint in your assertion inside the if, and whenever your asserts fail, you can see how you got there. With a macro, that's no possible.

Modern compilers do a really good job of inlining things when appropriate, given half a chance.